Can we write this function as a convolution product?
Let $\lambda_{sym^{r}f}(n)$ be the $n-$th coefficient in the
Dirichlet series representing the symmetric power $L-$function
attached to a primitive form $f$ of weight $k$ and level $N$. It is known that $\lambda_{sym^{r}f}(n)$ is a multiplicative function. My question is the following:
Can we write $\lambda_{{\rm sym}^rf}(n)$ as a convolution product of two arithmetic functions? And what are explicitly those functions ?

If you mean Dirichlet convolution then I believe the answer to your question is yes.

Yes  it is and what are these functions?

Every arithmetic function $f$ can be decomposed into a convolution. For example, $f=1\ast g$, where $g:=\mu\ast f$. So you need to be more specific about what you want.

If $b(1)\ne0$ and $b^{-1}(n)$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $b(n)$, then $a(n)$ can be evaluated as the Dirichlet convolution $a(n)=c(n) * b(n)$ where $c(n)$ is the Dirichlet convolution $c(n)=a(n) * b^{-1}(n)$ . There is no requirement for $a(n)$ to be multiplicative.
